# JWT token not authenticating correctly

Tags: python, jwt, fastapi

I'm building a API and I'm trying to implement jwt tokens.

I've got these two pieces of code which are responsible for the JWT stuff:

```
# Responsible for signinh, encoding, decoding and returning JWTs
JWT_SECRET = config("secret")
JWT_ALGORITHM = config("algorithm")

# This returns the generated tokens
def token_response(token: str):
    return {
        "access token": token
    }

# This is used for signing the JWT string
def signJWT(userID: str) -> Dict[str, str]:
    payload = {
        "userID": userID,
        "expiry": time.time() + 600
    }
    token = jwt.encode(payload, JWT_SECRET, algorithm=JWT_ALGORITHM)
    return token_response(token)

def decodeJWT(token: str) -> dict:
    try:
        decode_token = jwt.decode(token, JWT_SECRET, algorithms=[JWT_ALGORITHM])
        return decode_token if decode_token['expires'] >= time.time() else None
    except:
        return {}
```

and:

```
class JWTBearer(HTTPBearer):
    def __init__(self, auto_error: bool = True):
        super(JWTBearer, self).__init__(auto_error=auto_error)

    async def __call__(self, request: Request):
        credentials: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = await super(JWTBearer, self).__call__(request)
        if credentials:
            if not credentials.scheme == "Bearer":
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid authentication scheme.")
            if not self.verify_jwt(credentials.credentials):
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid token or expired token.")
            return credentials.credentials
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, **detail="Invalid authorization code."**)

    def verify_jwt(self, jwtoken: str) -> bool:
        isTokenValid: bool = False

        try:
            payload = decodeJWT(jwtoken)
        except:
            payload = None
        if payload:
            isTokenValid = True
            
        return isTokenValid
```

Well with this, I can generate the token, but when I try to validade it, I get `detail="Invalid token or expired token."`

I can't seem to find why it's not authenticating. Of course, if I remove the 'if' from the code, any string will be valid... So I assume is something around that part.

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/).

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

Just add "Bearer " in Authorization string before token in header

### Bit longer answer

Authorization header should contain token AND authorization method. Without method fastAPI don't know what to do with this token. In your case, authorization method is Bearer.
Problem here is that fastAPI can't handle exception when header missing auth.method normally and gives misleading exception descriptions (In my case decription was "exception: no description")

If you want to create app which should connect to your API with authorization, than add authorization method to header:

```
requests.post(self.apiFullAddress+postfix, json=postData, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + self.accessTocken})
```

For web app also:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
      'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' \
      -H 'accept: application/json' \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer YoUr_ToKeN' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -d '{
      "data": "SomeData",
      "moredata": "SomeMoreData"
    }'
```